# How to download full article text from Pubmed?

Tags: ruby, bioinformatics, text-mining, biopython, pubmed

I am working on a project that requires to work with Genia corpus. According to the literature Genia Corpus is made from articles extracted by searching 3 Mesh terms : “transcription factor”, “blood cell” and “human” on Medline/Pubmed. I want to extract full text article(which are freely available) for the articles in Genia corpus from Pubmed. I have tried many approaches but I am not able to find a way to download full text in text or XML or Pdf format.

Using Entrez utils provided by NCBI :

1. I have tried using the approach mentioned here - 
   http://www.hpa-bioinformatics.org.uk/bioruby-api/classes/Bio/NCBI/REST/EFetch/Methods.html#M002197

   which uses the Ruby gem Bio like this to get the information for a given PubMed ID - 
   Bio::NCBI::REST::EFetch.pubmed(15496913)

   But, it doesn't return the full text for the PMID.
2. Internally, it makes a call like this - 
   http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=1372388&retmode=text&rettype=medline

   But, both the Ruby gem and the above call don't return the full text.
3. On further Internet search, I found that the allowed values for PubMed for rettype and retmode don't have an option to get the full text, as mentioned in the table here - 
   http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/table/chapter4.T._valid_values_of__retmode_and/?report=objectonly
4. All the examples and other scripts I have seen on the Internet are only about extracting abstracts. authors etc. and none of them discuss extracting the full text.
5. Here is another link that I found that uses Python package Bio, but only accesses the information about authors - 
   https://www.biostars.org/p/172296/

How can I download full text of the article in text or XML or Pdf format using Entrez utils provided by NCBI? Or are there already available scripts or web crawlers that I can use?

Comment: Can you post a link to one of those articles you want to download and specify what part of it you need?

Comment: I want to download the free full text available for articles on Pubmed using PMIDs. For ex: If I query by PMID is 10438913 in pubmed search bar here (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed), then pubmed results show that this article is free article. So, clicking on this article I go to http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10438913 and on the right upper side you would a clickable icon saying "Final version free". If you click on this you get pdf version. Now, how could I automate this step for multiple articles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `biopython` to get articles which are on PubMedCentral and then get PDF from it. For all articles which are hosted somewhere else, it is difficult to get a generic solution to get the PDF.

It seems that PubMedCentral does not want you to download articles in bulk. Requests via `urllib` are blocked, but the same URL works from a browser.

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "Your.Name.Here@example.org"


#id is a string list with pubmed IDs
#two of have a public PMC article, one does not
handle = Entrez.efetch("pubmed", id="19304878,19088134", retmode="xml")

records = Entrez.parse(handle)
#checks for all records if they have a PMC identifier
#prints the URL for downloading the PDF
for record in records:
    if record.get('MedlineCitation'):
        if record['MedlineCitation'].get('OtherID'):
           for other_id in record['MedlineCitation']['OtherID']:
               if other_id.title().startswith('Pmc'):
                   print('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/%s/pdf/' % (other_id.title().upper()))
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this works like a charm to download pdfs. But I have still confusion I queried 15 PMIDs on pubmed website and it shows me for 9 PMIDs that they have free text available. When I ran your script it just gave me 1. Could you please explain the relation of PMID - PMC you mentioned in comment in the code. I am confused about it.

Comment: @KahiniWadhawan: Can you add the list of PubMed IDs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the exact same problem using ruby. So far I was able to achieve moderate success by doing the following with ruby:

1. use the Mechanize+esearch from eutils to get an XML of your pubmed search, and then use Mechanize/Nokogiri to parse the PMIDs from the XML
2. use the Mechanize+ID converter to convert the PMIDs to PMCIDs (when available). If you really are only interested in the papers available on PMC, you can set up the esearch to return PMCIDs as well.
3. once you have the PMCIDs, you can use Mechanize to access the webpage, click on the pdf click on the page, and use Mechanize to save the file.

It's by no means straightforward but still not that bad. There is a gem that claims to do the same (https://github.com/billgreenwald/Pubmed-Batch-Download). I plan to test that out soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `XML` or `JSON` by PubMed ID or PMC, then you want to use the *"BioC API"* to access PubMed Central (PMC) Open Access articles.

(see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/bionlp/APIs/BioC-PMC/ )

Here an [code-example](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/bionlp/RESTful/pmcoa.cgi/BioC_xml/19088134/ascii):

```
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/bionlp/RESTful/pmcoa.cgi/BioC_xml/19088134/ascii
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough solution I have been using recently. It works with the DOI system and handles redirection to plos one and arxiv.

```
import urllib
import os
import uuid
def download_paper(url, save_path=f"{uuid.uuid4().hex}.pdf"):
    success_string = f"paper saved successfully at {os.path.join(os.path.abspath(save_path))}"
    if url.endswith('.pdf'):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(pdf_url, save_path)
        return success_string
    if 'doi' in url:
        doi = paper_id = "/".join(url.split("/")[-2:])
        # Construct the Crossref API URL
        print(doi)
        doi_url = f"https://doi.org/{doi}"

        # Send a GET request to the doi.org URL
        response = requests.get(doi_url, allow_redirects=True)

        # Check if the request was successful
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Extract the final URL after redirection
            url = response.url

    if 'arxiv' in url:
        # URL del paper su arXiv

        # get paper ID from url
        paper_id = url.split("/")[-1]

        # build resource url
        pdf_url = f"http://arxiv.org/pdf/{paper_id}.pdf"

        # download
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(pdf_url, save_path)
        return success_string

    else: 
        if '/full' in url:
            # example 
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url.replace('/full','/pdf'))
            return success_string
        if 'plos.org' in url:
            final_url = url.replace('article?', 'article/file?')
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(final_url, save_path)
            return success_string
    
    return f'failed to download {url}'
```

Not long time ago I also found out about (Semantic Scholar)[https://api.semanticscholar.org/api-docs/] which is an API that provides you the free-access links of (also) PubMed articles. You can request an API Key for free at their website.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `fake_useragent` installed, the following code works for me to download PubMed Central PDF files:

```
import os
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from pathlib import Path


ua = UserAgent()
print(ua.chrome)
header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}
print(header)

r = requests.get('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMCxxxxxxxx/pdf/', headers=header)

filename = Path(r.url).name
destination_path = r'C:\temp'
fullpath = os.path.join(destination_path, filename)

local_filename = Path(fullpath)
local_filename.write_bytes(r.content)

print("File ", fullpath, " downloaded")
```